# Edit link in views leads to wrong node

Tags: 7, views

Just before the title field I have added a "Content: Edit link" in several of my views to make it easy to edit nodes. In the Rewrite section for this item I have added this to change the edit symbol:

```
<img src="/sites/all/themes/mysite/images/application_edit.png" alt="Edit symbol" height="16" width="16">
```

Now I have discovered that the Edit link redirects to the wrong node. The link looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/node/25305/edit?destination=node/24207
```

How can I make it direct the user to the right node? Should I enable Output this field as a link and add the node ID manually? I am not quite sure how to do that using the replacement patterns.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it the easy way. I enabled "Output this field as a link", added the field "Content: nid" as the first field and then changed my rewritten field to this:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.se/node/[nid]/edit?destination=node/[nid]"><img src="/sites/all/themes/mysite/images/application_edit.png" alt="Edit symbol" height="16" width="16"></a>
```

And now it works. Hope this helps somebody.